# Automate file browse action using chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, automation, filebrowse

Is there a way, to automate file browse and select action of HTML Input FileUpload Object, using chrome extension ?

Like 'sendkeys' in selenium. (driver.FindElement(By.Id("Update_file")).SendKeys(DS_File) )

Also is 'sendkeys' supported in chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to emulate the actions taken by a user to select a file in de file selector? Because that is impossible.
The only thing that works is sendKeys, but as you already mentioned it, I am not sure that is what you are asking for.

Take a look at https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/best-practices-tips-selenium-file-upload